# Openoffice doesn't show open window

Tags: windows-7, openoffice, openoffice-calc

I use Open Calc to open some CSV files directly from Windows Explorer but the open window doesn't show up over all the rest of opened windows and I must to minimize all the other windows one by one to find it, so I decide to open Calc before and click over open button most of times works but after a wake up from suspend mode the window just doesn't show up and Calc is unresponsive; doesn't appear to be hang up in Windows Task Manager but the UI is really stuck.

I'm using W7 x64 8GB of RAM and OpenOffice 4.

There's a configuration issue or just a bug?
If is a bug, There's a way around this?

Comment: Why are you still using OpenOffice? It'd pretty much Zombieware at this point...  I would remove it an switch to LibreOffice.

Comment: Because I didn't know that, the server still available and  the version is newer than the version I had before.

Comment: It is still being "updated", but there hasn't been a major release update since 2013 when 4.0 was released, and hasn't seen anything but security fixes or major bug fixes since 2014... LibreOffice has kind of taken the role as the "defacto" open source standard in office software suite for some time now and it is still actively being developed and enhanced. I am not saying it is the answer to your problem, but it likely would be.